# Creating a Dynamic Where Clause as a Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to dynamically append where conditions into a single expression-object, then pass that expression-object into a method that will use it.  However, I keep getting "class name is not available at this point".

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I finally was able to create a [**working example here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153260/are-linq-to-sql-dynamic-where-clauses-even-possible-in-framework-3-5).

**The Code Look Like:**

```
    var view = new vw_QuickFindResult();

   // This wont compile
    Expression<Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>> where = Expression<Func<vw_QuickFindResult, bool>>(view, true);

    // Build LIKE Statement
    var searches = new List<String>(searchText.Split(' '));
    searches.ForEach(productName =>
    {
        productName.Replace('"', '%');
        productName.Replace('*', '%');
        where = x => SqlMethods.Like(view.DocumentName, productName);
    });

    return DocumentCollectionService.ListQuickFind(where);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one problem:

```
where = x => SqlMethods.Like(view.DocumentName, productName);
```

You're ignoring the `x` here, instead using `view` which you've just initialized. I suspect you want:

```
where = x => SqlMethods.Like(x.DocumentName, productName);
```

However that will *replace* the existing `where` expression each time. I think you should be using [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) by Joe Albhari. I'd avoid using `ForEach` too, personally:

```
var where = PredicateBuilder.False<vw_QuickFindResult>();

// Build LIKE Statement
foreach (string productName in searchText.Split(' '))
{
    string like = productName.Replace('"', '%');
                             .Replace('*', '%');
    where = where.Or(x => SqlMethods.Like(view.DocumentName, like));
}

return DocumentCollectionService.ListQuickFind(where);
```

(I'm guessing at the functionality you want; you may want `PredicateBuilder.True` and the `And` extension method instead.)

Comment: This is AWESOME! QUESTION: What if I also wanted to create a dynamic OrderBy?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO: That becomes trickier, as then you've got to sort out the target property type as well. In most cases where there's a fixed set of orderings, I suspect a switch statement is the easiest way of achieving them.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm completely new to Linq-To_SQL and this REALLY saved me a LOT of time.